# How can I filter out some lines of a plain org-mode list when exporting?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Under a given task I have a list of lines, some of which are done sub-tasks which I have tagged with `:done`. For example:

```
- this thing I completed earlier :done
- this is stuff I did this week
  - I might have a sublist with a link in it
- and other stuff this week
- and stuff for next week :todo
```

When I export this to my report I want to hide the `:done` line. I think the solution for this is to use filters but:

```
(defun my-filter-out-done-lines (s backend info)
    "Filter out lines ending in :done"
    (apply 'concat
           (--remove (s-matches? (rx ":done" (zero-or-more blank) eol) it)
                     (s-slice-at (rx bol (one-or-more blank) "-") s))))

(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-status-report 'ascii
    :filters-alist
    '((:filter-plain-list . my-filter-out-done-lines)))
```

But I'm still removing lines that don't end in `:done` (I think it's being greedy) and links in removed lines are being rendered at the bottom.

Am I on the right path or is there a simpler way? I don't really want all these additional notes to become full subtasks.

Comment: Replace `concat` with `apply 'concat`. `--remove` returns a list of strings and `concat` should get the strings as arguments. It should not get the list of strings as argument.

Comment: OK I've manged to get the thing executing OK but I have two problems left. Firstly my test is overly greedy at throwing away lines. Secondly I need to supress the generation of links for lines I threw away.

Comment: So I've solved the first problem once I figured out that s-slice doesn't need the one-or-more blank regex as the strings are already stipped of leading spaces. However for hiding the links I need to somehow get the location of the link being processed out of the text properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out you just needed to know the string for plain lists didn't have leading spaces. Also although the :done tags may look as though they are on the same line in display there may be newlines in the actual string data. So tweaking you got:

```
(defun my-filter-out-done-lines (s backend info)                                                                                                                           
  "Filter out lines ending in :done"                                                                                                                                       
  (apply 
    'concat                                                                                                                                                           
    (--remove 
      (s-matches? (rx ":done" (zero-or-more blank) eol) it)                                                                                                   
      (s-slice-at (rx bol "-") s))))                                                                                                                          

(org-export-define-derived-backend 'my-status-report 'ascii
  :filters-alist                                                                                                                                                           
  '((:filter-plain-list . my-filter-out-done-lines)))
```